# Create a local, non-syncing table using Azure MobileServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

MobileServiceClient's sync tables are doing great. However, I need to maintain a client-located, non-syncing table in the mobile/client app.

My google skills are failing me cos i keep getting the offline-sync table tutorial.

Anyone knows how to maintain a non-syncing table using MobileServiceClient?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Same as a Sync table.  The differences are:

- Your table class does not include the Sync specifier
- You don't need to PullAsync() any more since the query is executed against the backend.

Reference here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#instantiating

Comment: i really should read the whole documentation at least once. it's already there! my usual technique of basing what to read by looking at the table of contents has failed me more than once now.

Comment: when you say the query is executed against the backend are you saying the backend at the server? from what's happening and how i understand the link, it looks like the mobile client needs to be online for the table to work. what im looking for on the other hand is just a mobile client located table with no relation to the server database.

Comment: i.e. the client doesnt need to be online to insert/edit/retrieve entries and said entries are not saved on the cloud.

Comment: You will need to use a different techology for this.  I'd suggest SQLite since that is already available to you if you are doing offline sync.